# Placing two shapes at separate position using gltranslatef opengl

Tags: c++, qt, opengl-es-2.0

Placing two shapes at separate position using `glTranslatef` .I draw two square shapes using OpenGL by using `glTranslatef` function.`glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW)` display both square shapes on one UI.

Here is my code:

```cpp
void drawSIGN( double dispX[], double dispY[]) {
    
    int const var1=dispX[1], var2=dispY[1], var3=dispX[2], var4=dispY[2];
    
    glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW)
    glPushMatrix();

        glTranslatef(var1- 5, var2 - 5, 0)
        
        glBegin(GL_LINES);
        glVertex2f(0 - 2, 0 - 2);
        glVertex2f(0 + 2, 0 - 2);
        glVertex2f(0 + 2, 0 - 2);
        glVertex2f(0 + 2, 0 + 2);
        glVertex2f(0 + 2, 0 + 2);
        glVertex2f(0 - 2, 0 + 2);
        glVertex2f(0 - 2, 0 + 2);
        glVertex2f(0 - 2, 0 - 2);
        glEnd();
    
    glPopMatrix();
        
    glPushMatrix();      
    
    glTranslatef(var3- 5, var4 - 5, 0);
        
        glBegin(GL_LINES);
        glVertex2f(0 - 2, 0 - 2);
        glVertex2f(0 + 2, 0 - 2);
        glVertex2f(0 + 2, 0 - 2);
        glVertex2f(0 + 2, 0 + 2);
        glVertex2f(0 + 2, 0 + 2);
        glVertex2f(0 - 2, 0 + 2);
        glVertex2f(0 - 2, 0 + 2);
        glVertex2f(0 - 2, 0 - 2);
        glEnd();
    glPopMatrix();
}
```

I am calling this function like this:

```cpp
double dispX[10],dispY[10];

drawSIGN( dispX, dispY);
```

I want when `dispX[1]=null,dispY[1]=null` not `int or 0` the shape created by `dispX[1],dispY[1]` by `glTranslatef` function should disappear and other shape created by `dispX[2] dispY[2]` which has not `0` integer value should reamin .But `glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW)` stop the disppear of shape whose `glTranslatef` has not valid values .Kindly tell me alternate function to `glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW)` in opengl which place both square and make appear whoes `dispX,dispY` are valid and make disappear whoes `dispX,dispY` are not valid in opengl?

Comment: Repeating questions to attract attention is not welcome. [Placing two shapes at separate position using gltranslatef opengl](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71570490/placing-two-shapes-at-separate-position-using-gltranslatef-opengl). If you want to improve a question, you can edit the question.

Comment: kindly refrech page. That question was deleted.

Comment: It's deleted because you deleted it instead of editing it.

Comment: @aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa DV: The question is, how is your current post different from the deleted one? Why don't you just update the deleted post?

Comment: I have search and added this `glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW)` function  from internet.Now the question statement and detail is change because program is behaving in new way because of using this function `glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW)`.So this question is of new type based on previous script